# findIndex of lodash in es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash, babeljs

I always depends on findIndex of lodash and splice to rerender my updated data, I'm looking to ditch lodash as I'm compiling with babel now, what can be done to improve below code?

```
onDoneUpdatedUserStatus(user) {

    //this.users means existing array of object of existing users

    const index = findIndex(this.users, { user_id: user.user_id });
    if (index > -1) {
        this.users.splice(index, 1, user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
this.users = this.users.map(oldUser => oldUser.id === user.id ? user : oldUser);
```

Comment: this is to remove the item, I want to splice it not delete it.

Comment: In that case: `this.users = this.users.map(oldUser => oldUser.id === user.id ? user : oldUser);`

Comment: so findIndex and splice is useless?

Comment: I wouldn't say they're useless, but I find that I can get almost everything done with some combination of map, filter and reduce

Answer (score 2):

You can store your users in a `Map` from user ids to users instead of an array. Then you just need to write

```
this.users.delete(user.user_id);
```

This will also speed up your lookup time.

Comment: store users in a map? what's that?

Comment: @Alan Then use `.set()`. Map is faster than array for these kinds of operations (constant time instead of linear). You can find docs for Map here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 1):

JS Array also has a findIndex method which is useful:

```
onDoneUpdatedUserStatus(user) {
    const index = this.users.findIndex(u => u.user_id === user.user_id);
    if (index > -1) {
        this.users.splice(index, 1, user);
    }
}
```